# CMake: Best practices for differing lib paths with ExternalProject_Add

Tags: cmake, linker, external-project

I have a small project whose `CMakeLists.txt` looks something like this:

```
include(ExternalProject)
ExternalProject_Add(gainput_project
  PREFIX gainput
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/jkuhlmann/gainput.git
  GIT_TAG e21b15f0bc3dd3f1a745fe89a966a2457e940142
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(gainput_project SOURCE_DIR)
ExternalProject_Get_Property(gainput_project BINARY_DIR)
set(GAINPUT_SOURCE_DIR "${SOURCE_DIR}")
set(GAINPUT_BINARY_DIR "${BINARY_DIR}")

add_executable(demo main.cpp)
add_dependencies(demo gainput_project)

target_include_directories(demo PUBLIC
  SYSTEM ${GAINPUT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include
)

# TODO: this is bad
if(WIN32)
  target_link_libraries(demo PUBLIC
    debug ${GAINPUT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/Debug/gainput-d.lib
    optimized ${GAINPUT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/Release/gainput.lib
  )
else()
  target_link_libraries(demo PUBLIC
    debug ${GAINPUT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/gainput-d.so
    optimized ${GAINPUT_BINARY_DIR}/lib/gainput.so
  )
endif()
```

Obviously, those calls to `target_link_libraries` are not ideal; they are very repetitive and I am explicitly writing paths and filenames that the build system should already know.  **What is the best way to handle the different output directories and filenames from the external project?**

Is there a way I can query the external project to get the *actual* output dir? (e.g. via [`ExternalProject_Get_Property`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/ExternalProject.html#command:externalproject_get_property)?)   Is there some magical generator expression I can use?  (`ExternalProject_Get_Property(gainput_project RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY)` does not work.)

It seems like [`find_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html#command:find_library) would work, *except* that the output library does not exist at configure time, so that fails.

Maybe I should set the external project's `INSTALL_DIR` to some hard-coded directory that I control and always use that?  (Would it still get the `Debug` and `Release` subdirectories on Windows?)

Would the [`FetchContent`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) module give me better access to the outputs of the included project?  I don't see anything obvious in the docs there.

Idk, I've already tried quite a few ideas and nothing has worked so far.  I feel like I may be missing something fundemental - this is the first time I've used `ExternalProject`.  Any tips?

Comment: "I am explicitly writing paths and filenames that the build system should already know." - No, build system knows nothing about paths in a subproject used via `ExternalProject_Add`. Look: the subproject is not even configured when you run `cmake` for the main project. "Is there a way I can query the external project to get the *actual* output dir?" - Only if the specific subproject supports such query. Or read the subproject's documentation. Or read the subproject's `CMakeLists.txt`. Build system does't know even about `-d` suffix for a debug library.

Comment: `FetchContent` approach (which is eventually calls `add_subdirectory`) allows you to build a subproject as a **part of the main project**. That is, the subproject and the main project would **share** targets, variables, etc. This sharing could be an advantage (e.g. in the main project you can directly use targets defined in the subproject) or a disadvantage (e.g. projects could have conflicting requirements for the variables settings). `ExternalProject_Add` builds a subproject in its **own environment**, so a conflict for CMake variables isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks @Tsyvarev.  `FetchContent` plus generator expressions (e.g. `$<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:gainput>`) seems to be what I was looking for.  Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tsyvarev suggested, I solved this by switching from `ExternalProject` to `FetchContent` and then using a generator expression to find the output file:

```
include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(gainput
  PREFIX gainput
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/jkuhlmann/gainput.git
  GIT_TAG e21b15f0bc3dd3f1a745fe89a966a2457e940142
  INSTALL_COMMAND ""
)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(gainput)

add_executable(demo main.cpp)
add_dependencies(demo gainput)

target_include_directories(demo PUBLIC
  SYSTEM ${gainput_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/include
)

target_link_libraries(demo PUBLIC
  $<TARGET_LINKER_FILE:gainput>
)
```